# JS - Не работает развернуть / свернуть

Tags: javascript

Не работает JS код в браузерах, то есть нажимаешь кнопку развернуть, а оно не реагирует. В хроме все работает как надо, но вот в остальных браузерах не хочет.

Вот код :

```
var halfText = $('.otra').innerHeight() / 2,
    textHeight = $('.otra').innerHeight();

$('.otra').css('height', $('.otra').innerHeight() / 2);

$('.show-hide').click(function() {
    if( $('.otra').innerHeight() == halfText ) {
        $('.otra').animate({ height: textHeight }, 500);
        $(this).text('Скрыть');
    } else {
        $('.otra').animate({ height: halfText }, 500);
        $(this).text('Показать полное описание');
    }
});
```

Comment: Проверил на всех актуальных версиях браузера, везде работает, на jQuery версии 2.1.1,у тебя в консоли нет ошибок?

Comment: Ошибок в консоли нету, в Mozilla firefox в инспекторе height изначально 400 , при нажатии  на кнопку меняется только дробная часть, например из 400.125 на 400.135 и потом обратно на 125.А в хроме height меняется с 400 на 700. Как будто в мозиле что то мешает ей расшириться, в IE тоже самое